# Problem with template class with multiple parameter constructor in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I am getting the error when calling the template constructor

```
error C2664: 'Storage<T2>::Storage(MyClass *,T2 *)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int *' to 'int **'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T2=int *
1>        ]
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Below is my code

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class MyClass
{
private:
    int a1;
    int b;
public:
    MyClass(){}
};

template <class T2>
class Storage
{
private:
    MyClass* m;
    T2* m_value;
public:
    Storage(MyClass* m,T2* value)
    {
        m_value =value;
    }

    ~Storage()
    {
    }
};

// Main Function 
int main() 
{ 
    MyClass x;
    int *y = new int();
    Storage <int*> test1 (&x, y); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Please help me to resolve my problem.
How to set the template class properly for my requirement.

Comment: Perfectly fine error message. `T2` is `int**`, your constructor expects a pointer to it.

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher  T2 should be generic pointer. I dont know how to correct the template class to make T2 as generic pointer

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, but we don't know what you want to do! `y` is an intermediate pointer anyway. You probably need just a `Storage<int>`, not a `Storage<int*>`.

Comment: looks like a rather convoluted way to leak a pointer. what do you want to achieve?

Comment: it can be CDialog* or CWnd*  or pointer of derived class CDialog also, for my requirement T2 is generic pointer only.

Comment: when `T2` is a pointer, lets say `int*`, then `T2* m_value;` is a `int**`, you have to many stars. Without knowing what the code is supposed to do, I dont know which you should remove

Comment: @user463035818 what is the syntax for T2 to point to pointer and then how to call template constructor.

Comment: `T2` is already a pointer, you can change your constructor parameter to `T2 value`

Comment: @Matthieu T2 represents generic type but the member of the template is T2* and If I call the constructor  by Storage<int> test1(&x,y)  I am getting error 'Storage' : too few template arguments and 'Storage' : class has no constructors

Comment: "T2 represents generic type" ... once you instantiate the template, there is nothing generic about `T2`, in your example `T2` is `int*` nothing else

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store a pointer to `int`, use `Storage<int>`. Works perfectly well:

```
int main() 
{ 
    MyClass x;
    int *y = new int();
    Storage <int> test1 (&x, y); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: when using microsoft visual c++ compiler it is not compiling

Comment: Template Partial Specialization requires syntax like this, template <MyClass I, class T2> class Storage<I*,T2*> { private: I* m; T2 m_value; but I am getting the error C2993: 'MyClass' : illegal type for non-type template parameter 'I'"", how to reolve this?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with partial specialization. The code works as is.

Comment: You have another problem, probably with the type you want to store. Start a a new question with the relevant details, this question has been answered.

Comment: It is working now but when I tried before it was not working

Answer (score 0):

Pure technically, you have two ways to make the code compile (without modifying the template):

```
MyClass x;
int* y = new int();
Storage<int*> test1(&x, &y);
//                      ^ (!)

template <class T2>  // T2 is int* ...
class Storage
{
    Storage(MyClass* m, T2* value); // ... so you need to pass a pointer to int* (i. e. int**) 
};
```

In this variant, `test1` would hold a pointer to `y` itself – *not* a pointer to the object `y` points to. I pretty much doubt, though, this is what you actually want...

The second variant:

```
MyClass x;
int* y = new int();
Storage<int> test1(&x, y); 

template <class T2>  // T2 now is int ...
class Storage
{
    Storage(MyClass* m, T2* value); // ... and you pass a pointer to int
};
```

Now, the value of `y` is copied into the `value` parameter (i. e. `y` and `value` – and later `m_value` – point to the same object).

A third variant requires modifying the template:

```
template <class T2>
class Storage
{
private:
    MyClass* m;
    T2 m_value; // no pointer!
public:
    Storage(MyClass* m, T2 value) // no pointer!
        : m_value(value) // side note: you should prefer object's initializer list
                         // (not to be confused with std::initializer_list!)
    { }
};

Storage<int*> test1(&x, y);
```

Now, T2 itself is a pointer again, and you effectively get the same result as in second variant (and to get the same effect as in first, you'd have to specify `Storage<int**>`).

Direct comparison of second and third variant:

```
template <class T2>            template <class T2>
class Storage                  class Storage
{                              {
    T2* m_value;                   T2 m_value;
};                             };
Storage<int> test1(&x, y);     Storage<int*> test1(&x, y);
```

Internally, you have both times a pointer to int – difference is in how you got there...

Comment: I need pointer member only. I need to call some functions of that class through that pointer.

Comment: @user369287 That's pretty much what I assume... First variant is only for explanation/illustration (*'I pretty much doubt [...]'*). Both second and third variant give you the pointer you want. Which one is better? Depends on use case... In your specific case, I'd prefer second variant.

Comment: Template Partial Specialization requires syntax like this,

template <MyClass I, class T2>
class Storage<I*,T2*>
{
private:
I* m;
T2 m_value;

but I am getting the error  C2993: 'MyClass' : illegal type for non-type template parameter 'I'"", how to reolve this?

Comment: @user369287 Syntactically: `template<class I, class T2> Storage<T2*> { };` - while the definition actually seems to compile (GCC at least), you'll have difficulties to *instantiate* this 'specialisation' - be aware that you are *adding* an additional template parameter, the original template just had one. Not sure if this even is illegal... Why would you need it at all?